# iOS - allow specific contact to call in silent mode

Tags: ios, swift

I am working in project that allow user choose some contact to call even phone in silent mode .

is this available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API supplied by Apple that will allow you to do this. Your is is sandboxed and can not interacte fully with others apps.

Comment: thank you for answer , I find way play sound in silent mode , can I use it to solve my problem

Comment: No, because you can not interacte with a phone call, you can only detect that a phone is started. You can not get the phone number of the call. So there is no way to do what you want. It would be a huge privacy breach as well.

Comment: how truecaller detect  incoming phone number and show up its name ??

Comment: They don't, you can only search for number in their app. See their FAQ: http://www.truecaller.com/support#/iPhone/a1

Comment: so no way to approach that , according to @ronan answer he mention we can approach ring if I add contact to favorite list via code ?

Comment: As ronan stated you can add people to the favorite list programmatically. You can not interacte with the phone app on iOS in any way. You might be able to do it for jailbroke phones and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

When people switch their iPhone to silence mode, only those who have been added to favorite list can call successufully.

The problem is that favorite list is belong to `Phone` app, it's inside the app's sandbox, private API used by Apple. Developer should not use these kind of API, we can only use public API

Comment: Did you read the answer, it clearly states that it is done by private API and those a not accessible for AppStore apps.